# Keyboard combination ctrl+shift+ ( f9 - f12 ) not working

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have been using **Ubuntu 18.04** for a while and everything went well. But now I noticed something weird. The shortcut for hiding all tools windows in IDEA stopped working. I checked my keyboard shortcuts to see if I have any collisions, but I didn't find any.

Then I used "Show keyboard layout" to visualize my keyboard and I noticed, that the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd>, is **not registered**. I see that that **<kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> are pressed**, but **not <kbd>f12</kbd>**. The same thing happens for <kbd>f9</kbd>, <kbd>f10</kbd> and <kbd>f11</kbd>. But it works fine with <kbd>f1</kbd>-<kbd>f8</kbd> (I see all three of them being pressed in "show keyboard layout") and any other keyboard combinations.

I use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> quite extensively and I would prefer not changing the shortcut combination if possible.

Comment: Can you share the picture of your keyboard please?

Comment: Did you find the reason why the keys are not registered?

Comment: This is affecting me too. I was trying to use my usual keyboard combo ctrl+shift+= in IntelliJ - see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206903365-Gnome-IDEA-and-ctrl-shift-hotkey

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on my Ubuntu 20.04. I have toggled off all GNOME Shell Extensions and it works fine now, so some extension might be the cause for you too.

You might want to test each extension to find which one is overriding your keys. In my case, the *Clipboard Indicator* holds the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Other places to look at are `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/` in *dconf Editor* and *Keyboard shortcuts* in *Settings*.

Comment: It's driving me crazy! Why if Clipboard Indicator binds ctrl + F12 then I can't use Idea ctrl + shift + F12?

Comment: I started ticket https://github.com/Tudmotu/gnome-shell-extension-clipboard-indicator/issues/376